# python: regexp: matching and replacing

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm developing a sort of "parser for a custom script" in python using regexps.
Please don't answer about if regexp is a good solution of not for this kind of operation... It is long (and off-topic) to explain why I'm choosing to use regexp, even if I know the problems of using regexp for parsing.

Now I proceed with the question. We start with this scenario:

This is the line I will read from a file, that I need to parse with my regexp:

```
something = { call _ "string to ""capture"" " } #non consumed
```

now I can do something like this:

```
import re
regex1 = re.compile(r'^([^"]*?)(_?)\s*"((?:""|[^"])*)"')
mystr = r'something = { call _ "string to ""capture"" " } #non consumed'
mymatch = re.search(regex1, mystr)
```

so I can obtain those capture groups:

- 0: all mystr line until the last quote
- 1: all things before quotation (I need this match to verify a thing later)
- 2: '_' or '' (depending if there is an underscore rightly before quotation [there can be spaces between underscore and quotation])
- 3: quotation (where "" is considered as a character and not a closing quote)

I need to know those groups, so using `re.search` is fine (becouse I can use `mymatch.group(n)` to check the value of the single captured groups).

But... after I used all groups from `1` to `3`, I will need to reduce mystr so it will contain only "non consumed string by the 'successfull' regexp"

I could do this with:

```
mystr = mystr[ len(mymatch.group(0)): ]
```

so a working code could be this one:

```
import re
regex1 = re.compile(r'^([^"]*?)(_?)\s*"((?:""|[^"])*)"')
mystr = r'something = { call _ "string to ""capture"" " } #non consumed'
mymatch = re.search(regex1, mystr)
# code here that uses mymatch.group(n)
mystr = mystr[ len(mymatch.group(0)): ] # clear from mystr what was parsed by the regexp
```

but I'd like to see if there are other ways to do this.
Can you suggest other code approaches different by the one I provided?"

---

Searches:

[Not useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278950/python-regexp-to-replace-recognized-pattern-with-the-pattern-itself-and-the-repl): it ask only about replacing, but not about single match groups. Here I am asking how to do both actions together in a good way

[Not useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460538/pattern-matching-and-replacing-in-python): For (almost) the same reason as the first link

Comment: **good** is a relative term and encompasses manything- i think this question should be asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know about code review. However I edited my question with a "can you suggest other code approaches different by the one I provided?" hoping it is less ambigous than before. I will problably move this question to codereview as you pointed. Thank for help.

Comment: If http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the right place where to ask this question (and probably is, I think Sislam is right) may I ask to an admin to move this question from here to codereview? (in this way I will avoid to post twice the same topic here in stackexcerge sites)

Comment: Too much of an example to be on topic for Code Review IMO. We ask for the real code there, not MVCEs.